# Haskell help : Replacing terms within a lambda-term with new variables! (Simple mistake needs fixing...)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I am trying to write a function, when passed:

```
variables VX = ["v1",..."vn"]
```

And a `Term`, will replace all `Terms` within the passed `Term` with a `variable from VX` respectively.

My function works to a certain extent, for the example:

```
S ((\a. \x. (\y. a c) x b) (\f. \x. x) 0)
```

It returns:

```
S (V1 V1 0)
```

Rather than what it should return:

```
S (V1 V2 0)
```

Here is my function along with the tests. Can anyone spot a mistake I have made perhaps?

```
termToExpression :: [Var] -> Term -> Expression
termToExpression [] a = termToExpr a
termToExpression _ (TermVar y) = ExpressionVar y
termToExpression (x : _) (TermLambda a b) = ExpressionVar x 
termToExpression (x : xs) (TermApp n m) = ExpressionApp (termToExpression (x : xs) n) (termToExpression (x : xs) m)
```

Comment: Your case for `TermApp` doesn't remove the `x` in the second recursive call. It puts the `x` back on the front of the stack so that the rest of the `xs` are never visited.

Comment: @4castle I see that now thanks. But have now changed this line to `termToExpression (x : xs) (Apply n m) = ExpressionApp (termToExpression (x : xs) n) (termToExpression (xs) m)` and it returns `S (V2 (\f. \x. x) 0)` instead of desired `S(V1 V2 0)

Comment: I guess I don't understand how your `Show` instance works. Can you show what `example2` looks like in your code?

Comment: "Replacing a **term** with a **variable**" is kind of an unusual thing to do with lambda calculus. A term is a composite value (possibly with other terms inside it) whereas a variable is a placeholder for another term. It's much more common to replace a **variable** with a **term** (that's called _substitution_). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @4castle sure, example2 is defined as follows: `example2 = Apply (Variable "S") (Apply (Apply example (numeral 0)) (Variable "0"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that

```
ExpressionApp (termToExpression (x : xs) n) (termToExpression (x : xs) m)
```

makes two recursive calls, and intuitively the first one should "consume" any number of variables to generate its output. After that, the second recursive call should not use the variables already "consumed" by the first one.

In a sense, there is some sort of state which is being modified by each call: the list of variables gets partially consumed.

To model that, you will need to first write an auxiliary recursive function which returns, together with the new lambda term, the list of not-yet-consumed variables.

```
aux :: [Var] -> Term -> (Expression, [Var])
```

Now, when you need to make two recursive calls to `aux`, you can make the first one, get the list of not-consumed variables from its result, and make the second recursive call using that list.

(A more advanced solution would be to use a `State [Var]` monad, but I guess you want to write a basic solution.)